# Goで数字がキーのJsonをUnmarshalしたい

Tags: go, json, api

Go言語を使って構造体を定義し、下記レスポンスをUnmarshalでパースしたいです。`authors`のところが数字をキーとして使用しています。

https://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=en&dest=ja&format=json&phrase=test&pretty=true

以前コチラの質問で`simple-json`でのパースについて質問させていただきましたが、標準ライブラリのUnmarshalではどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。`json:"-"`を指定すればフィールドを無視できるようですが、その時構造体の要素はどのように定義すればいいでしょうか。

[キーが変動するJsonをパースしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19393/%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E5%A4%89%E5%8B%95%E3%81%99%E3%82%8Bjson%E3%82%92%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、`tuc.authors`(下記プログラム内の `TucItem.Authors` に対応)を `interface{}` 型で unmarshaling します。レスポンス(JSON format)の最後に `authors` タグがあるので、これを map に取り込んで先の `TucItem.Authors` にマッチングさせて、`Author` 型のデータに入れ替えます(対応するデータがない場合は `nil` が入ります)。ただ、`interface{}` 型なので必要に応じて type assertion を行う事になります。

```golang
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
  "net/http"
  "net/url"
  "strconv"
)

type Translate struct {
  Result  string
  Tuc     []TucItem
  Phrase  string
  From    string
  Dest    string
  Authors map[string]Author
}

type TucItem struct {
  Phrase    PhraseItem
  Meanings  []PhraseItem
  MeaningId float64
  Authors   []interface{}
}

type PhraseItem struct {
  Text     string
  Language string
}

type Author struct {
  U   string
  Id  uint
  N   string
  Url string
}

func main() {
  values := url.Values{}
  values.Add("format", "json")
  values.Add("from", "en")
  values.Add("dest", "ja")
  values.Add("phrase", "test")

  resp, err := http.Get("https://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?" + values.Encode())
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

  defer resp.Body.Close()
  rf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

  var result Translate
  json.Unmarshal(rf, &result)

  // Replace authors data
  for _, tuc := range result.Tuc {
    for i, id := range tuc.Authors {
      aid := int(id.(float64))
      v, ok := result.Authors[strconv.Itoa(aid)]
      if ok {
        tuc.Authors[i] = v
      } else {
        tuc.Authors[i] = nil
      }
    }
  }

  // Show authors
  for _, tuc := range result.Tuc {
    text := tuc.Phrase.Text
    if len(text) == 0 {
      text = tuc.Meanings[0].Text[0:5] + "..."
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s:", text)
    for _, author := range tuc.Authors {
      fmt.Printf(" %#v", author)
    }
    fmt.Println("")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

参考情報ですが

厳密にはJSONではkeyに数字を使えず、文字列しか使えないそうです。

[JavaScript Object Notation - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation#.E8.A1.A8.E8.A8.98.E6.96.B9.E6.B3.95)

> ここで注意することはキーとして使うデータ型は文字列に限ることである。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。Jsonでは数字の文字列になっていました。必要無い部分だったので、構造体から除外したところその部分はパースされずに無視されました。